# Resizing video best practices (frame size)

Tags: flash, video, flv

I have read the following which is from Best Practices for Encoding Video with the VP6 Codec on the Adobe website here - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/encoding_video_print.html. It is talking about common video ratios (320x240, 640x480)

> Although these ratios are standard,
>   and should be used to avoid distorting
>   the video, the size of the encoded
>   video is not set in stone. The
>   original web video sizes used heights
>   and widths that were evenly divisible
>   by 16. This was mandatory for many
>   early codecs. Although this is not
>   necessary for modern codecs, you
>   should stick to even heights and
>   widths.

What do they mean by 'even heights and widths'. I am thinking about encoding my video at 400x300 to make it slightly bigger, this is still 4x3 format but should I just stick at 320x240 and resize it on the screen? Clearly there are benefits to this in terms of storage size and delivery costs.

In some places on my site I want to show the video at 400x300 but in others I want it to play full screen so this is why I am wondering if a larger original size (400x300) will give better results when blown up.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VP6 and Sorenson work best with video frame sizes that are multiples of 16, which you stated. For optimal results, you should go with something that is a multiple of 16. For example, something closer to your range might be 384 x 288 or 448 x 336.

Honestly though, I haven't ever seen many problems caused by using a non-16 multiple for FLVs. And, the bigger video size will bring better quality (albeit at the cost of more bandwidth because it'll be a bigger size video).

So, I'd go with a size that's a multiple of 16 if you can, but don't lose sleep over it. And, I'd go with a bigger video size over a smaller one just to keep it a multiple of 16. However, I'd aim for that 16x sweet zone.

Also, consider switching to MP4s with H.264 content. Flash 9+ can play it (a very, very, very large percentage of the market share of Flash). Plus, you'll get MUCH better compression than VP6.